# Performing gesture on view prevents camera action

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scenekit, scnnode

I have a basic 3d interactive globe. I'm using the function **centerCameraOnDot** to move the camera to center on different parts of the globe. When I run the code and call **centerCameraOnDot** everything runs smoothly.
I can even run the function multiple times in a row on different locations, and it will animate to each one correctly.

However, if I perform any gesture on the view stop and then call the function after a few seconds, the camera never animates to the new location.
I did some debugging and the function does execute and **newCameraPosition** is calculated correctly.

However, the camera action doesn't perform.
This may be a result of gestures modifying the state of the scene/camera.

How do I go about performing these actions regardless of previous gestures?

I tried reinitializing the view and running the function and this obviously works, but is not practical.

```
import Foundation
import SceneKit
import CoreImage
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

public typealias GenericController = UIViewController

public class GlobeViewController: GenericController {
    var nodePos: CGPoint? = nil
    public var earthNode: SCNNode!
    private var sceneView : SCNView!
    private var cameraNode: SCNNode!
    private var dotCount = 50000
    
    public init(earthRadius: Double) {
        self.earthRadius = earthRadius
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    public init(earthRadius: Double, dotCount: Int) {
        self.earthRadius = earthRadius
        self.dotCount = dotCount
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func centerCameraOnDot(dotPosition: SCNVector3) {
    let fixedDistance: Float = 6.0
    let newCameraPosition = dotPosition.normalized().scaled(to: fixedDistance)

    // Position animation
    let moveAction = SCNAction.move(to: newCameraPosition, duration: 1.5)

    // Set up lookAt constraint for orientation
    let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: earthNode)
    constraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true

    // Animate the transition
    SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1.5

    cameraNode.constraints = [constraint]
    cameraNode.runAction(moveAction)

    SCNTransaction.commit()
}

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupScene()
        
        setupParticles()
        
        setupCamera()
        setupGlobe()
        
        setupDotGeometry()
    }
    
    private func setupScene() {
        let scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView = SCNView(frame: view.frame)
        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor = .clear
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        sceneView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.addSubview(sceneView)
    }
        
    private func setupParticles() {
        guard let stars = SCNParticleSystem(named: "StarsParticles.scnp", inDirectory: nil) else { return }
        stars.isLightingEnabled = false
                
        if sceneView != nil {
            sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addParticleSystem(stars)
        }
    }
    
    private func setupCamera() {
        self.cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    }

    private func setupGlobe() {
        self.earthNode = EarthNode(radius: earthRadius, earthColor: earthColor, earthGlow: glowColor, earthReflection: reflectionColor)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(earthNode)
    }

    private func setupDotGeometry() {
        let textureMap = generateTextureMap(dots: dotCount, sphereRadius: CGFloat(earthRadius))

        let newYork = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.0682, longitude: -121.3153)
        let newYorkDot = closestDotPosition(to: newYork, in: textureMap)

        let dotColor = GenericColor(white: 1, alpha: 1)
        let oceanColor = GenericColor(cgColor: UIColor.systemRed.cgColor)
        let highlightColor = GenericColor(cgColor: UIColor.systemRed.cgColor)
        
        // threshold to determine if the pixel in the earth-dark.jpg represents terrain (0.03 represents rgb(7.65,7.65,7.65), which is almost black)
        let threshold: CGFloat = 0.03
        
        let dotGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: dotRadius)
        dotGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = dotColor
        dotGeometry.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant
        
        let highlightGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: dotRadius)
        highlightGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = highlightColor
        highlightGeometry.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant
        
        let oceanGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: dotRadius)
        oceanGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = oceanColor
        oceanGeometry.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant
        
        var positions = [SCNVector3]()
        var dotNodes = [SCNNode]()
        
        var highlightedNode: SCNNode? = nil
        
        for i in 0...textureMap.count - 1 {
            let u = textureMap[i].x
            let v = textureMap[i].y
            
            let pixelColor = self.getPixelColor(x: Int(u), y: Int(v))
            let isHighlight = u == newYorkDot.x && v == newYorkDot.y
            
            if (isHighlight) {
                let dotNode = SCNNode(geometry: highlightGeometry)
                dotNode.name = "NewYorkDot"
                dotNode.position = textureMap[i].position
                positions.append(dotNode.position)
                dotNodes.append(dotNode)
                
                print("myloc \(textureMap[i].position)")
                
                highlightedNode = dotNode
            } else if (pixelColor.red < threshold && pixelColor.green < threshold && pixelColor.blue < threshold) {
                let dotNode = SCNNode(geometry: dotGeometry)
                dotNode.name = "Other"
                dotNode.position = textureMap[i].position
                positions.append(dotNode.position)
                dotNodes.append(dotNode)
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let dotPositions = positions as NSArray
            let dotIndices = NSArray()
            let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: dotPositions as! [SCNVector3])
            let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: dotIndices as! [Int32], primitiveType: .point)
            
            let pointCloud = SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
            
            let pointCloudNode = SCNNode(geometry: pointCloud)
            for dotNode in dotNodes {
                pointCloudNode.addChildNode(dotNode)
            }
     
            self.sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(pointCloudNode)
            
            //performing gestures before this causes the bug
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                if let highlightedNode = highlightedNode {
                    self.centerCameraOnDot(dotPosition: highlightedNode.position)
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gestures on the view might be altering the state of the camera or the scene, preventing the camera from animating to a new position when `centerCameraOnDot` is called.

You should make sure any gesture-related modifications to the camera or the scene are either reset or properly handled before running the `centerCameraOnDot` function.

Before animating the camera to a new position, reset any transformations or constraints that might have been altered by gestures. That could be as simple as setting the camera to a known state or removing constraints added by gestures.
And check if there are any active gestures. If there are, you might need to wait until they are completed or forcefully end them.

Temporarily disable gesture recognizers when the camera animation starts and re-enable them after the animation is completed. That prevents any gesture interference during the camera movement.

```swift
func centerCameraOnDot(dotPosition: SCNVector3) {
    let fixedDistance: Float = 6.0
    let newCameraPosition = dotPosition.normalized().scaled(to: fixedDistance)

    // Disable gestures here
    sceneView.gestureRecognizers?.forEach { $0.isEnabled = false }

    // Reset camera state if needed
    // e.g., cameraNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Identity

    // Position animation
    let moveAction = SCNAction.move(to: newCameraPosition, duration: 1.5)

    // Set up lookAt constraint for orientation
    let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: earthNode)
    constraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true

    // Animate the transition
    SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1.5

    cameraNode.constraints = [constraint]
    cameraNode.runAction(moveAction) {
        // Re-enable gestures here
        self.sceneView.gestureRecognizers?.forEach { $0.isEnabled = true }
    }

    SCNTransaction.commit()
}
```

---

Another approach was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77513091/swift-detect-tap-on-child-scnnode-not-parent?noredirect=1#comment136689000_77513091) by [ColdLogic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217774/coldlogic):

> You have to use gesture recognizers if you want only specific things to happen during specific gestures.
> You can sort of accomplish the same thing with touchesBegan by checking the number of taps, state of the touch, and other factors. But it's easier to just use a [`UIPanGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer) or a [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer).

Using gesture recognizers like `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or `UITapGestureRecognizer` in your SceneKit application can provide more control over how user interactions affect the scene and the camera.
By using gesture recognizers, you can more easily disable or modify gesture interactions during camera animations. For example, you could disable a pan gesture recognizer while the camera is animating to prevent unintended interference.
And implementing custom gesture recognizers can enable you to manage the state of the scene and camera more effectively. For instance, you can set up a gesture recognizer specifically for moving the camera, and make sure it does not interfere with other scene interactions.

As an example:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupScene()
    // Other setup methods

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}

@objc func handlePanGesture(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // Handle the pan gesture
    if gesture.state == .began {
        // Optionally disable camera animation here
    } else if gesture.state == .changed {
        // Update camera or scene based on pan movement
    } else if gesture.state == .ended {
        // Optionally re-enable camera animation here
    }
}
```

That approach could help prevent the issue you are experiencing where gestures interfere with the `centerCameraOnDot` function.

---

> But what Im encountering is if I do any gesture on the view then stop and wait 10 seconds then run the camera animation, it just doesn't run.

If `SCNView.allowsCameraControl` is enabled, the built-in camera controls may be interfering with your custom animations. You can try explicitly disabling `allowsCameraControl` before your animation and re-enabling it afterward.

In addition to resetting the camera's transform, make sure all constraints (including any potential hidden constraints applied by SceneKit's default camera control) are removed or reset before starting the animation.

There might be ongoing animations or actions on the camera node that are not immediately visible. Checking and stopping these before starting a new animation could help. Sometimes, adding a slight delay before starting the animation allows the scene to settle after a gesture.

Your `centerCameraOnDot` function would then be:

```swift
func centerCameraOnDot(dotPosition: SCNVector3) {
    let fixedDistance: Float = 6.0
    let newCameraPosition = dotPosition.normalized().scaled(to: fixedDistance)

    // Disable built-in camera controls
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = false

    // Clear any existing animations or constraints
    cameraNode.removeAllActions()
    cameraNode.removeAllAnimations()
    cameraNode.constraints = nil

    // Reset camera state
    cameraNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Identity

    // Position animation
    let moveAction = SCNAction.move(to: newCameraPosition, duration: 1.5)

    // Set up lookAt constraint for orientation
    let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: earthNode)
    constraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true

    // Optionally add a delay here
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        // Animate the transition
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1.5

        self.cameraNode.constraints = [constraint]
        self.cameraNode.runAction(moveAction) {
            // Re-enable built-in camera controls
            self.sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        }

        SCNTransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

That way, the camera should be in a known state before starting the animation and that no conflicting actions are interfering. The slight delay before the animation can also help in situations where the scene might need a moment to settle after a gesture.

---

> I also found that if I simply add the line `sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode` at the very beginning of `centerCameraOnDot()`, then the camera action works even after a gesture. This line resets the globe to its original position, and then the camera is able to animate correctly.

The fact that setting `sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode` at the beginning of `centerCameraOnDot()` resolves the issue indicates that the internal state of the `SCNView` or its `pointOfView` is being altered by the gestures, even if it is not immediately visible through the properties of the `cameraNode`. That could be due to SceneKit's internal handling of camera controls and gesture interactions.

To avoid the visual reset caused by reassigning `cameraNode` to `sceneView.pointOfView`, you can try preserving the current camera position and orientation, then restoring them after reassigning `pointOfView`.

If you have not already, make sure the built-in camera controls (`allowsCameraControl`) are disabled during your custom camera movements. That can help prevent internal state changes caused by SceneKit's default handling of camera gestures.

It seems that the gesture interaction is somehow affecting `pointOfView` even if it is not visible in the `cameraNode` properties. You might want to investigate how gesture recognizers are set up and whether they interact with the `pointOfView` property.

As you correctly pointed out, UI updates, including enabling/disabling gesture recognizers, should be performed on the main thread. Here is how you can modify the relevant part of the code:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.sceneView.gestureRecognizers?.forEach { $0.isEnabled = true }
}
```

Given your findings, a potential modification to your `centerCameraOnDot` method could be:

```swift
func centerCameraOnDot(dotPosition: SCNVector3) {
    let fixedDistance: Float = 6.0
    let newCameraPosition = dotPosition.normalized().scaled(to: fixedDistance)

    // Preserve current camera state
    let currentPOV = sceneView.pointOfView
    let currentPosition = cameraNode.position
    let currentOrientation = cameraNode.orientation

    // Reset pointOfView to refresh internal state
    sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode

    // Restore camera state to avoid visual reset
    cameraNode.position = currentPosition
    cameraNode.orientation = currentOrientation

    // Your existing camera animation code
}
```

That code attempts to refresh the internal state by reassigning `pointOfView`, but then immediately restores the camera's position and orientation to prevent a visible jump. That might be a workaround to refresh whatever internal state is causing the issue without a noticeable visual impact.

Comment: Thanks. I think your solution helps with the case where the user is interacting with the view right when the animation starts, thus the reason you disable gestures when the action begins and enable at end. But what Im encountering is if I do any gesture on the view then stop and wait 10 seconds then run the camera animation, it just doesn't run. It may be because the previous gesture modifies the scene or camera state as you said. I tried **cameraNode.constraints = []** before the action and what you included **cameraNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Identity** but this didn't fix this issue.

Comment: @ahmed I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Tried this out, not working unfortunately. I also tried reseting the earth node in the same way and setting its orientation to **SCNQuaternion(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1)**. I added a longer delay and debugged all the nodes values to make sure their reset. Not sure what else could be causing it.

Comment: @ahmed Maybe SceneKit is maintaining an internal state that is not fully reset by altering the `cameraNode` or `earthNode` properties. You can try logging or inspecting all properties of these nodes to see if anything unusual stands out. If the issue persists, consider using a different method to control the camera. For instance, instead of moving the `cameraNode` directly, you might adjust the `SCNView`'s `pointOfView` property or use an intermediate `SCNNode` as a parent to the camera and manipulate that instead.

Comment: I debugged every property of cameraNode. I found that everything was just fine. But I also found that if I simply add the line **sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode** at the very beginning of **centerCameraOnDot()** then the camera action works even after a gesture. This line resets the globe to its original position, and then the camera is able to animate correctly. Im not sure why this even works because the sceneView's pointOfView is already set to the cameraNode. With this update does anything come to mind that would help me bypass this adjustment before the animation.

Comment: Also this line **self.sceneView.gestureRecognizers?.forEach { $0.isEnabled = true }** in your answer has to update on the main thread. Maybe add dispatch queue main async block.

Comment: @ahmed Good points, and good findings, well done! I have edited the answer to address your last two comments.